# How to test a Rails engine which should support both Rails 3 and Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I am working on a Rails engine. I have generated a Rails 4 engine and am starting to get set up for testing. I have added the `appraisals` gem as a development dependency so that I can test multiple versions of Rails. Here is my `Appraisals` file:

```
appraise 'rails-3.2' do
  gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.0'
end

appraise 'rails-4.0' do
  gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.0'
end

appraise 'rails-4.1' do
  gem 'rails', '~> 4.1.0'
end
```

When I run `bundle exec appraisals rake`, I get an error for the Rails 3 version:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for #<TestApp::Application:0x007fc7ac2db718>
```

I think this is because there is an API change between Rails 3 and Rails 4.

My question is: how should I set up my engine to test and support multiple versions of Rails?

Answer (score 1):

If you feel like digging into the source, you might check out Upmin, which tests multiple versions of Rails:

https://github.com/upmin/upmin-admin-ruby

Maybe related to this difference between 4.0 and 4.1 (search "configure")?

http://railsdiff.org/diff/v4.0.0/v4.1.0/

(You can see this difference in the Upmin config files, too.)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to ugly up your config with some conditionals. You should be able to access `Rails::VERSION`.

As an example, I have an Rails engine that supports Rails 4.1 and 4.2. In 4.2 they introduced `config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks`, so my dummy's `application.rb` has:

```rb
if Rails::VERSION::MAJOR >= 4 && Rails::VERSION::MINOR >= 2
  config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
end
```

Hope that helps.